# A trigonometry problem

Tags: trigonometry

Solve θ in $\sin^2θ$ - $\cos^2θ$ = 1

$$-1 = \cos^2θ - \sin^2θ \\ -1 = \cos(2θ)$$

What would be the next step to solve this enigma?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\displaystyle \cos2\theta=-1=\cos\pi$

$\implies2\theta=(2n+1)\pi$ where $n$ is any integer

---

Alternatively, $-\cos^2\theta=1-\sin^2\theta=\cos^2\theta$

$\implies \cos^2\theta=0 \implies \cos\theta=0$

$\implies \theta=(2m+1)\frac\pi2$ where $m$ is any integer

Comment: In the formula and identities sheet which formula did you use to get cosπ?

Comment: @LittleJon, I think,  values of some common Trigonometric ratios like $\arccos x, \arcsin x,\arctan x$ for $x=0,\pm1 $ etc. will remain in your memory with practice.

Comment: mhhh..... so for this problem the unit circle is not used correct.

Answer (score 2):

We know also that $$\sin^2 \theta +\cos^2\theta =1$$

This implies that $\cos^2 \theta = 0$. so that $\cos \theta =0$ - and the solution to that is well known. It is easily checked that every such solution solves the original equation.

Comment: $0=2 cos^2θ$ how do you get $cosθ=0$?

Comment: @LittleJon Well $2\neq 0$ so we can cancel it, and the only solution to $x^2=0$ is $x=0$.

Comment: Yes I think I am starting to get it you divided 2 under 0 and got 0 then you said $cos^2θ$ can only be 0 so you get cosθ which is $cosθ =cos(θ+2πn)$ any integer.

Answer (score 0):

**hint:**

On the unit circle what value of $y$ corresponds to an $x$ value of $-1$. What does that imply about $2\theta$?